# Find my iPhone app won't install on iPhone 6s

Tags: find-my-iphone

The "Find my iPhone" app won't install on my iPhone 6s. I tried several times directly from the App Store and I am unsuccessful

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What happens when you try to install?

Comment: It's already installed in (I think) iOS 9 or later.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please provide the OS version you're running including any errors you're receiving and steps you've already tried.  See [ask] on how to ask questions that have a good chance of getting answered. - From Review -

Answer (score 1):

I'm using iOS 10 Developer Beta 7. Find my iPhone is already installed. Just out of curiosity, I went to the App Store, and did a search for the app. Interestingly, the little "cloud" icon would seem to indicate that, although I have downloaded it in the past, it is NOT installed. This is not actually the case - it IS installed.

[image]

Try going to your main page and swiping down - this will enable the search feature. Then search for "Find iPhone." Just in case it's hidden in a folder, this will tell you if it is already installed.

[image]

Comment: This was true. Helped me as well. Thanks for posting this info